# Angular shared module via npm link

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I want to create a project with a shared module that contains some generic things and some components which are shared all over my apps (e.g. header).
Later this module will be added as dependency in package.json and should be installed via Nexus. But during development I want to npm link this from my filesystem, because I don´t want to go the "nexus way" every time I change something in the shared module.

My questions are:

- Can I use angular decorators (e.g. @Componennt or @NgModule) in this shared module?
- How to import all this shared module stuff into my actual project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:  yes but you have to build the library locally for each change.

Question 2:

- Create a folder in node_modules with the same name of your library as in your package.json
- Link this folder to the folder containing the locally built library (npm link)
- Use regular import statement in the typescript file

The problem at this point is that the whole thing does not work reliably. Therefore **it is better to use a monorepo** for this kind of problem.

A good tool for this is: https://nx.dev/angular/getting-started/why-nx